intercept a packet/request and block it in python scapy
I am working on a project where I analyze the traffic of my computer with scapy, I would like to be able to intercept the request and when it is a request to a certain IP address to be able to block it before it leaves, whether it is a request that goes from my computer to this IP address or whether the request comes from this IP to my computer
I tried a few avenues with Scapy but I can't find it

That's not possible. Scapy can listen for incoming packets or send packets but it is the job of your firewall (e.g., iptables on linux) to drop packets.
